# Run PowerShell X64bit in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

So I want to run a script in Visual Studio which contains cmdlets that only works using a 64bit version of PS and not the 32bit version. The problem is that the current VS Powershell is by default 32bit. How can I make or force VS to use the 64bit version.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a common issue on [Developer Comunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/x64-developer-powershell-for-vs-2019/943058). At the moment there isn't an option to launch the x64 bit version of the **Powershell** through Visual Studio, only the **CMD** supports the x64 bit version.

Although it is possible to run Powershell scripts in Visual Studio with a [third party tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsVS2022), which is explained on [Ironman Software](https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/daily-powershell/running-powershell-visual-studio/).